# What does this crontab line do?

Tags: bash, cron

The script [deployment_worker.sh](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5363697/deployment_worker.sh) is a control script in charge of stopping and starting a service each two hours... or so I think. Apparently this line in the crontab does something else, judging by the fact that the process comes back from hell pretty fast whenever I kill him:

```
* */2 * * * /srv/server_ctrl/deployment_worker.sh restart
```

In line 45 of [deployment_worker.sh](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5363697/deployment_worker.sh):

```
echo "Issuing service start" >> $CONTROL_LOG
```

I issue a line to the log file, and that line effectively *appears* in the log, which I think it means this file gets executed by somebody (not me!)... and the only one that comes to my mind is the cron daemon ....

So, here are my questions:

- What the above crontab line do?

Comment: Shouldn't you have 0 in the minute space if you want it run once every two hours, not 60 times every two hours?

Comment: @Joe That's the problem, how could I miss it!!??

Comment: An extra pair of eyes is always helpful for silly things like that :)   Or 20000 extra pairs of eyes, as SO would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run once every two hours:

```
 0   */2   *   *   *   <command-to-run>
```

So it's running once a minute from 12am to 12:59, then from 2:00am to 2:59, ... etc.

http://livecronjobs.com/how-to-run-cron-every-2-hour

Comment: In 8 minutes I will accept your answer. But judging by the other answers, it is a pretty non-obvious issue ;-)

Comment: I'm sort of impressed I got it right, actually; i'm really lousy at cron.  I have to look it up every single time as I only use it once every few months... means I have the right pages bookmarked I guess :0

Answer (score 0):

`* */2 * * *` mean run at midnight 0, 2 am, 4 am ... see `man crontab`

Comment: I think that's what the OP wants [and is not seeing].

Comment: Actually I am wrong.  It should be as 'Joe' had answered `0 */2 * * *`

Answer (score 0):

cron can run a script under whatever uid is necessary. if a common user has cron rights and adds something to their personal crontab, those cron jobs will run under THEIR ids. root can have its own crontab, and also control every other user's crontab as well.

so that cron line of yours could be run as root (if it's in root's crontab), or as some other user.

as for what it does, it runs the specified script every two hours.